# is < vector > threadsafe for read/write at different locations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety

this is a beginner question i guess but i couldn't find the answer to this particular question:

i have a standard (c++) vector v of size 10 and type int.

is it safe to have a thread alter all the even positions (v.at(0) = x; v.at(2) = y; etc.)
and another thread alter all the values for the odd positions (v.at(1) = a; v.at(3)=b;etc.) at the same time?

so, no changing of size, no push_back() etc. during the lifetime of these 2 threads.

if it is not safe, would the use of an array be a better way to do this?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`vector` does not provide any thread-safety guarantees, so technically the answer would be no.

In practice, you should be able to get away with it... until the day that someone (possibly you) makes a small change in one corner of the program and all hell breaks loose. I wouldn't feel comfortable doing this in any non-trivial program.

Comment: +1 for trying to avoid sleepless nights after this app is delivered and, worse, is enhanced/maintained :(

Comment: thanks for your answer. i see what you mean...
though:
how would you approach the problem? as the idea is to divide a rather big grid of variables into portions to share the calculation time. A lock on the whole grid/vector will slow down things quite a bit

Comment: @Benthebear: Maybe from the opposite side... generate the grid in parts, process each part independently with no locking, and finally merge the results. Could that work?

Comment: it could. things will be hard to read though. to get back to the original question, would an array [] make any difference here?

Comment: @Benthebear: An array would make the practical "it will work" verdict stand academically as well; if the loss of convenience doesn't hurt you, then go ahead. But by itself it won't solve the "may break in future" problem. You might want to consider passing the chunks of your array around as specially-crafted iterators; this way, the array partitioning will be opaque to your workers (no chance of mishap) and you will only have all such responsibility condensed into one piece of code (where all the iterators are created). Should be pretty maintenance-friendly.

Answer (score 7):

From MSDN: **[Thread Safety in the Standard C++ Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9ceah3b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

For reads to the same object, the object is thread safe for reading:

- From one thread at a time when no writers on other threads.
- From many threads at a time when no writers on other threads.

For writes to the same object, the object is thread safe for writing from one thread when no readers on other threads

For reads to different objects of the same class, the object is thread safe for reading:

- From one thread at a time.
- From one thread at a time when no writers on other threads.
- From many threads at a time.
- From many threads at a time when no writers on other threads.

For writes to different objects of the same class, the object is thread safe for writing:

- From one thread when no readers on other threads.
- From many threads.

So from the above, ***Theorotically, NO, it won't be threadsafe***.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically: No.

Practically: Yes (According how all well known STLs are implemented)

Comment: This should be practically No for `std::vector<bool>`. I just spent hours debugging a crazy bug where I had code similar to the one in the question, except it was a `std::vector<bool>`. For some reason, `std::vector<bool>` is a bitset with one bit per element. Because the processor loads words of 8 or more bits at a time, it won't be able to deal with `v[i]` and `v[i+1]` separately, so there are serious issues.

Answer (score 5):

It's machine-dependent. If you have a `vector<char>` the processor might not be able to load v[i] and v[i+1] in separate words. You may have cache consistency problems.

Both the compiler and processor might re-order instructions, which can break your program even if the above doesn't apply. [This is why C++0x has a memory model.](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/misc_slides/c++mm.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

The scenario you describe will be tread-safe - you effectively manipulate individual elements of a fixed size array (since `vector` size will not change during those operations), so you don't need any additional synchronization in the first place unless you manipulate any element from more than one thread (which is not you case).